# Editing netbeans.config to set jdk path results in an error

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

Hi I recently upgraded to windows 8.

For some reason after I installed netbeans it did not point to my instalation of jdk.

I had this problem before under windows 7 and I modified the path by editing the netbeans.config file.

I tryed to do the same thing but for some reason when I try to save the file in notepad++ I get an error stating that the file is opened in another program.

I tryed doing the same with wordpad an there I got the error that access is denied.

I restarted my computer two times same problem still persists.

Is there any other way of setting the path for the jdk?Maybe from any of netbeans option?

Answer (score 3):

i was trying to this but that didn't work for me cause i need privileges..

My solution:

Just open notepadd++ as Admin and then you can do whatever you want..
If that doesn't work, delete the file and then create a new one with the same content(don't forget to run notepad++ as admin)

Comment: Thanks for this dude: "don't forget to run notepad++ as admin"

Answer (score 1):

1. copy the content of netbeans.confg
2. delete it
3. create new file with the same name
4. past and perform your edit

Answer (score 0):

Make shure netbeans isn't open when you edit the config file.

If setting of `netbeans_jdkhome` in the `netbeans.conf` doesn't work, you can outcomment it (insert a `#` before). Now netbeans will use the *default* JDK installed. However, you a proper `path` for java is required (and `JAVA_HOME`).

Its also possible to set the JDK by commandline argument: `--jdkhome <dir>`

**See:**

- [Setting JDK by command line](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqJdkHome)
- [Netbeans.conf - see JDK part](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf)